# How to Integrate Sandbox code with Visual Studio Code

Tags: salesforcedx

Trying to Setup Salesforce DX IDE environment with Visual Studio Code
I'm facing issue while using this command--> Retrieve by package.xml and Get All Files from org.
Can you please help me out to integrate with VS code.

Comment: What kind of issue are you facing exactly?

Comment: Retrieve Errors Thumb down  and some time connect time out

Answer (score 2):

You don't. [Yet](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/123). Visual Studio Code using Salesforce Extensions is supposed to work with Scratch Orgs (via SalesforceDX), not Sandboxes.

If you need to access and edit the metadata (classes, pages, components) in your sandbox you either use the console or another tool like Eclipse with the Force.com plugin.

Cheer up, [Salesforce is planning to support the usage of the development tools in sandboxes as well](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/123), but in the future.

Comment: I cant fully agree. There is possibility to use sfdx to fetch metadata and there is extension that can do it out of the box

Comment: Forcecode the name is.

Comment: ForceCode is deprecated, just like MavensMate (the equivalent for Sublime Text 3) is.

Comment: You *can* do it with sandboxes, but it's not a very polished workflow at all (pushing and pulling the SFDX Metadata API commands). Better to use another solution with VS Code or another editor.

Comment: It's possible now via the Preview of the SFDX VSCode extension. More here: https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/wiki/Develop-Against-Any-Org-in-Visual-Studio-Code